# What does $\sum_{i/k_i = k}$ mean in the equation below?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, dynamical-systems, network, statistical-mechanics

I was reading chapter 5 of *Dynamical Processes on Complex Networks*, which discusses the Ising model, where I encountered the following equation for the average magnetization of the class of nodes with degree k: $$\langle \sigma \rangle_k = \frac{1}{N_k}\sum_{i/k_i = k} \langle \sigma_i \rangle$$

I'm particularly confused by the notation $$\sum_{i/k_i = k}$$

Can anyone explain what this means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i\mid k_i=k} a_i,$$ also written $$\sum\limits_{i: k_i=k} a_i,$$ means to sum $a_i$ over indices $i$ such that $k_i=k$.

To make it clearer that the formula is an average, I probably would have first defined $N_k = \{i \in N: k_i = k\}$ as the **set** of nodes with degree $k$ and then used the expression
$$\langle \sigma \rangle_k = \frac{1}{|N_k|}\sum_{i\in N_k} \langle \sigma_i \rangle$$

Comment: `/` and `|` are equivalent notations in this case, then?

Comment: Yes, but $\mid$ and $:$ are more common.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense in this context. I'll accept the answer as soon as the system allows me to.

Comment: If $i/k_i=k$ for integers, then it seems that $k\mid i$, rather than $i\mid k$. Does dynamical systems really standardly reverse things/misuse $/$ in this way?

Comment: @MarkS. there is no division here. The $/$ or $\mid$ indicates *such that* here. Better notation would have been $i\in N: k_i=k$.